# HttpParams - How To Query Multiple Columns With REST Api?

Tags: angular

This works for one column of the target table:

```
this.params = {
    'filter': `${dbColumn2} = ${skillId}`
}
```

All of these, and more permutations of them, fail for querying two columns.  Either they won't compile or more commonly they are rejected because the columns require integers and the queries are changing the integers to strings.  Id's are numbers.

Nothing on the Web is helpful at all.  I'm using Postgres but not sure that is the issue for a REST api.  This is for dev on my computer. Eventually this migrates to server code when I get to that point.  Still have to learn that. Any ideas?

```
  // 'filter': `(${dbColumn1}=${skillId})` & `(${dbColumn2}=${skillId})`
  // 'filter': `${dbColumn1} & ${dbColumn2} = ${skillId}`,
  // 'filter': `${dbColumn1}=${skillId}` '&' `${dbColumn2}=${skillId}`,
  // 'filter': `${dbColumn1}=${skillId} AND ${dbColumn2}=${skillId}`,
  // 'filter': `${dbColumn1}=${skillId}' AND '${dbColumn2}=${skillId}`,
  // 'filter': `${dbColumn1}=${skillId} & ${dbColumn2}=${skillId}`,
```

Comment: Your view shouldn't be aware or your persistence layer, and shouldn't try to pass SQL where clauses to the backend. Pass plain old parameters, and create your SQL query, based on those parameters, on the backend, using a prepared statement.

Comment: @JB, as I mentioned this is just for dev on my computer.  It seems like it should work but doesn't.  I don't know how to do the server side yet.  Enough trouble now learning RxJS :-)

Comment: Just because it runs only on your computer doesn't mean you should do things in a bad way. Besides we don't know what you actually pass as parameters, an what you're doing with them on the server.

Comment: @JB  I can't do something bad even if it helps speed up dev?  :-)  I didn't want to learn Node.js scripting on the server yet.  It isn't easy learning how to code and dealing with the whole Angular stack.  I'm just searching a couple of db columns for a number.  It could live in one, both, or neither of the columns depending on what was selected in a dropdown in each column in a component.  I just want to hack this for now and move on.  All the stuff that will get moved to the server lives on one service at the top level.

Comment: Apparently, it doesn't speed up anything, since you're lost. What do you have on the server? You realize you need something,right? You can't query PostgreSQL over HTTP.

Comment: I'm using Dreamfactory as middleware and it supports Node.  I have been querying Postgres but two columns fails.  It can be done with REST, plenty of advice online, but I want to use HttpParams.  That is where the problem is.  Yes, I am losing time that I could be learning Node.  I'm thinking about that over a few glasses of wine this evening.  :-)